# the codes that i tried cant run blcd motors

Tags: arduino

I'm making a control free drone using Arduino uno3, and want to run bldc motors on it. I provided the right voltage battery in addition. however, the motors don't run at all.

I tried everything. and a calibration code that I found on google, works properly. the code was designed to put int value in the serial monitor. I don't use serial monitor so, I pass an int value as a parameter of the motor.writeMicroseconds function. but it doesn't work at all. I almost tried everything but to fail. I put the right pin on the board. but it didnt work still tho.

```
int MAX_SIGNAL 2000
int MIN_SIGNAL 1000 //signals
int MOTOR_PINA 9
int MOTOR_PINB 8
int MOTOR_PINC 7
int MOTOR_PIND 6

Servo motor1;
Servo motor2;
Servo motor3;
Servo motor4; //motorpin init

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  motor1.attach(MOTOR_PINA,1000,2000);
  motor2.attach(MOTOR_PINB,1000,2000);
  motor3.attach(MOTOR_PINC,1000,2000);
  motor4.attach(MOTOR_PIND,1000,2000); //motor connect to board, set min,max speed 


  motor1.writeMicroseconds(MAX_SIGNAL);
  motor2.writeMicroseconds(MAX_SIGNAL);
  motor3.writeMicroseconds(MAX_SIGNAL);
  motor4.writeMicroseconds(MAX_SIGNAL);

  delay(100);
  motor1.writeMicroseconds(MAX_SIGNAL);
  motor2.writeMicroseconds(MAX_SIGNAL);
  motor3.writeMicroseconds(MAX_SIGNAL);
  motor4.writeMicroseconds(MAX_SIGNAL);
  //calibration
}

void loop() {

    int DELAY = 1200;
    motor1.writeMicroseconds(DELAY);      
    motor2.writeMicroseconds(DELAY);      
    motor3.writeMicroseconds(DELAY);      
    motor4.writeMicroseconds(DELAY);    
    delay(1000);    
}
```

no error msg. but the motors don't run.

Comment: i used many codes but i wrote code in sum

Comment: Seem your not in the right forum, try posting it to other stachexchange site. Try in this site https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ or in here https://arduino.stackexchange.com/